# How does one use SQL Server's HASHBYTES in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I need to use the `HASHBYTES` function in Entity Framework and I don't see how to. I tried using the `SqlFunctions` class but I don't see anything for hashbytes.

How can I use hashbytes in Entity Framework?

Example of what I want converted:

```
HASHBYTES('md5', cast(Rand() + item_id as varchar))
```

Comment: Have you tried raw sql?

Comment: @Khalil Right now I'm getting around not having it by writing my whole SQL in a stored procedure and calling my stored procedure in entity framework. This doesn't give me deferred execution and I'm more comfortable writing in entity framework.